# Displaying Errors in HHVM

Tags: php, hhvm

I was thinking of using HHVM in my development environment. However, I have encountered two significant issues.

First, no matter what I try, I cannot get HHVM to display a PHP stack trace in the browser window when an exception or error occurs. I've tried using `set_error_handler` and various other approaches. Has anyone figured out a way to display errors and exception stack traces in the browser window?

Second, the error log file is filled with "\n". I know that is supposed to cause a carriage return. However, it's not. Instead, it just makes the logs hard to read. Has anyone figured out a way to get rid of all of the "\n" in the log files?

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/runtime-options#logging , what have you tried?

Comment: I did read that. No luck. They just affect the verbosity of the log files. I've tried using whoops. I have tried using set_error_handler. I've tried googling every word combination describing the issue.

Comment: For the second issue (`\n`), there's an open issue at https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4437, which includes a PR that's actively being worked on.